# PyCharm runs nosetests on directories, but not on files

Tags: pycharm, nose

I have PyCharm and I am trying to launch nosetests on a file. I already set the default test runner as nose. If I right click on a directory, I get a context menu entry "Run 'Nosetests in tests'". Invoking it works well and runs all the tests in the directory. However, if I right click on a file, it tries to run the file as a python program. The file is called test_something.py, and it contains routines that are recognized as tests.

Comment: Did you ever discover anything here, Stefano? I'm still seeing this.

Comment: @Dan nothing. I gave up and started them from the terminal

Comment: darn, that's too bad.

Comment: filed a bug with them: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18282

Answer (score 0):

Just looking for this for myself and found: [Jetbrains Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-nose-test.html). Most be a new feature. At least since version 2016.1 under the configuration tab for Run/Debug you can now select the radio button labeled "All tests in folder". Even though I edited an already existing configuration I had to reselect the folder I wanted to run.

[image]